# Can you access a non static method in a derived class from a different classes static method in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am having trouble accessing a non static method in a derived class from a different class.

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String args)
   {
      LinkedList myList = new LinkedListExtension();

      TestMethods.methodOne(myList);// passed the method myList
   }
}

public class TestMethods
{
   public static void methodOne(final LinkedList myList)
   {
      myList.clear(); // this is the part I am having trouble with
   }
}

public class LinkedList
{
   protected static class Node
   {
      public Comparable data;
      public Node next;
      public Node(final Comparable data)
      {
         this.data = data;
         this.next = null;
      }
         public Node()
      {
         this.data = null;
         this.next = null;
      }
         public Node(final Comparable data, final Node next)
      {
         this.next = next;
         this.data = data;
      }
   }

   protected Node head;
    protected int size;

   public LinkedList()
   {
      this.head = new Node();
      this.size = 0;
   }
}

public class LinkedListExtension extends LinkedList
{
   public void clear()
   {
      this.head = new Node(); 
      this.size = 0;
   }
}
```

I know if I had the clear() method within the LinkedList class the code would compile and function correctly. So without changing anything in the LinkedList class and the Test class how would one go about calling the clear() method in LinkedList extension? Is it at all possible? I apologize if this question is not clear I am a noob when it comes to programming and am still having a hard time understanding inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `LinkedList` doesn't have a `clear()` method. You could move it from `LinkedListExtension` to `LinkedList`, or you could program to the `LinkedListExtension`

```
public static void methodOne(final LinkedListExtension myList) {
    myList.clear();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this which causes a compiling error in the test class. I am trying to not change anything in either Test class or LinkedList class. I am only wondering if this is at all possible or if the changes you mentioned are the only way of implementing the clear() method from its location in TestMethods

Comment: The `clear()` method isn't in your `LinkedList` class. You could add it there. Or, you must use the `LinkedListExtension` class (which has a `clear()` method currently). What you are trying to change or not change is immaterial, those are your two choices.